# How to translate העלם in the context of שבת

Tags: translation, maseches-shabbos, english, intent-accident-purposely, memory

The beginning of the seventh chapter of *Bavli Shabas* (and its commentaries) speaks of instances in which someone forgets that the day is *Shabas*, forgets that there is such a thing as *Shabas* altogether, or forgets that a particular action is forbidden on *Shabas*; he therefore does a forbidden action on *Shabas*. One Hebrew word that keeps getting used there is "העלם". Briefly, an action is said to be in a העלם if the actor forgot something significant (one of the aforementioned facts), and the העלם isn't over until the actor realizes his error. Thus, the *g'mara* discusses whether things occur "in one העלם or in two", etc.

In reading and attempting to translate the *g'mara*, I find myself stymied by this word. I keep translating it as "a forgetting", which is not really a word. (I mean, it's in the dictionary. But not as meaning "a time period of forgetting, until realization". Or, at least, no one uses it that way.) However, everything else I can think of is too long to be usable with any frequency: brevity is important to me. I would appreciate suggestions.

As with all "please suggest your best…" questions on this site, please list not only *what* you like but *why* you think it fits the bill.

Comment: "Skipped his mind" comes to mind - You know and you knew but there was a העלם between those 2.

Comment: "Absent-mindedness"?

Comment: When I learned these halachos in yeshiva, I remember my rebbe also used "a forgetting"

Comment: "Incident of forgetfulness"?

Comment: I can't think of an English equivalent. But you may want to ask over on [English Language & Usage SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: period of forgetfulness works. But I strongly agree with @SethJ

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is at best a question about the Hebrew language, and at worst a question about the English language.

Comment: Perhaps "prolonged incident of forgetfulness with multiple inadvertent violations of Shabbath during that period"?

Comment: The word means "disappearance" (as in, from his conscious mind/memory; Not sure what need more than that...?)

Comment: @Loewian, as stated in the question, I seek a good way to translate it while reading the _g'mara_. If you think "if he did two labors in one disappearance" is a good translation, then I encourage you to post an answer.

Comment: @mevaqesh, please note that this is not a mere translation question but a question about translation specifically in the context of a particular discussion in the _g'mara_. (Compare my comment, just above, addressed to Loewian.) Note also that questions about "general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to Judaism" [are on-topic](/help/on-topic).

Comment: @msh210 OP knows _what_ it means conceptually. He just does not know how to describe that concept in English.

Comment: @mevaqesh, correct. That's why he (I) asked for translation suggestions.

Comment: Jews make up words all the time. I would have no qualms about using "a forgetting".

Comment: This question is about a detail of learning and teaching Gemara. It is 100% on-topic.

Comment: I'm still not clear what you're asking. Is it that you want to know if there is a single English word that conveys שכחה? If so, that doesn't really sound on topic.

Comment: @Loewian, not "שכחה" but "העלם", and specifically in the context of שבת.

Comment: @Loewian the question is asking for a recommended way to convey a specific Torah concept such that it'll be understood by English-speaking readers, concise enough to be used repeatedly in written Torah discussion related to that concept. Think of this more as "how shall I teach this?" than as "what should dictionaries say?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest **oblivion**.

[Wiktionary's](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oblivion) first definition is:

> The state of forgetfulness or distraction; fig. confused

It seems to me that the distracted kind of forgetfulness is the phenomenon discussed in the laws of Sabbath.

Wiktionary notes:

> (*usually uncountable, plural oblivions*)

Although this word is usually not treated as  discrete instance, it is sometimes used that way, so I think it would be reasonable to use it in that sense. If you pluralize it at least once in your discussion, that's one way to make it clear that you're talking about discrete instances. You can also make that explicit when you introduce the term.

As a bonus, *oblivion* also has a sense of

> The state of being completely forgotten.

which sounds very much like the "disappearance" sense of העלם pointed out [by ray](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/62418/2) and [by Loewian](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/62433/2).

Answer (score 2):

Try Fugue? Fugue:

> a state or period of loss of awareness of one's identity, often coupled with flight from one's usual environment, associated with certain forms of hysteria and epilepsy.

[Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugue_state)

Comment: Heh, I think fugue is (as you've indicated) loss of awareness of one's own identity, not of (e.g.) the laws of _Shabas_. I don't think I'll be using this translation. But +1 for creativity.

Comment: For a jew forgetting Shabbos is like forgetting one's own identity, no?

Answer (score 1):

The Hebrew word itself only means "disappearance" (as in, from his conscious mind/memory) which means it needs to be interpreted contextually even in the original. If you are looking for a translation that incorporates the contextual explanation, perhaps try: "[dismissal from mind](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dismiss%20from%20mind)" or "act of forgetting/disremembering" (or "disrememberance" if you're not ardently opposed to neologism).

Answer (score -1):

the word means concealed or hidden as in bamidbar 5:13

> "and a man lie with her carnally, but it was hidden (neelam) from her
>   husband's eyes, but she was secluded [with the suspected adulterer]
>   and there was no witness against her, and she was not seized."

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is seeking a translation that is useful in the context of its meaning in Shabbath.